# exchange server 2012 update does not work

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchange-2013, windows-update

We have an Exchange Server 2013 with a connection to Microsoft 365 running locally on our  network. We use Windows Server 2012 R2.

This Exchange Server should now receive the cumulative update CU23. Unfortunately, the update process did not go through properly and the Exchange Server services are no longer available locally.

The installation ended with error 80040667

Already Googled possible workarounds unfortunately did not provide a solution.

Error Logs: https://pastebin.com/raw/mghQ18zz
https://pastebin.com/JdVBhutM

[The Update we are trying to install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0VtN.png)

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2thA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Noticed you have also posted in other forums:

MS Q&A: [exchange server 2012 update does not work](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/299042/exchange-server-2012-update-does-not-work.html?)

Spiceworks: [exchange server 2012 update does not work](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2309357-exchange-server-2012-update-does-not-work?from_forum=33)

It's recommended to check the provided suggestions there first and see how it goes.